# MSL insert Query not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have the following code but its not working no new entry is created in the database + its returning error, I cannot get the query to execute.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO request_send ('message,create_time,sdate,edate,guest,from_userid,to_userid,hostid') VALUES(':ms,:create_tim,:sdat,:edat,:gues,:from_useri,:to_useri,:hosti')";
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare( $query );
        $stmt ->bindParam(':ms', $req);
        $stmt->bindParam(':create_tim', $c_time);
        $stmt->bindParam(':sdat', $start);
        $stmt->bindParam(':edat', $end);
        $stmt->bindParam(':gues', $guest);
        $stmt->bindParam(':from_useri', $fromid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':to_useri', $touser);
        $stmt->bindParam(':hosti', $hostid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':whoareyou', $whoareyou);
     // check for successfull query
        if ( $stmt->execute() ){
             $response['status'] = 'success';
           } else {
                $response['status'] = 'error';
}
```

Help me to fix the issue.
[edit] managed to solve it after rewriting the query

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Always try to find out what the exact error message is, then you can usually solve your own problem. What does `echo $stmt->errorInfo();` give you?

Comment: Remove quotes in parentheses.

Comment: @kojow7 it just returns me array that's all

Comment: @mim. i did nothing changed

Comment: @takachou Then please add a try catch block and show us your exception.

Comment: @takachou, sorry, my mistake. Try this: `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` - It will give you the full error description as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You got an excess `bind_param()`

```
$stmt->bindParam(':whoareyou', $whoareyou);
```

Either remove it or add `:whoareyou` in the query